# determined the run time of specific insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion

Assuming the array length is n, the array is arranged by 1 and 0,
from the first index to the index t there are only 1's,
from the index t+1 till n, only 0's.
example [1,1,1,1....,1,0,0....0,0,0]

the algorithm for the insertion sort:

```
InsertionSort(Input: integer n, array A)
{
 for j = 1 to n {
 newnum = A[j]
 i = j-1
 while ( i > 0 and newnum < A[i] )
 {
 A[i+1] = A[i]
 i = i-1
 }
 A[i+1] = newnum
 }
}
```

this is what i have got so far:

\sum _1^n:\left(c1+\sum _1^{n-t}c2:\right)

Answer (score 0):

The inner while loop moves the first `0` to the right of the list of `1`s to the left of the list of `1`s. There are `t` `1`s to *jump* over, and `(n - t)` `0`s to move altogether.

Thus you have `t * (n - t)`.

You may or may not wish to add another `t` for the time taken to reach the first `0` in the array.